# copy dependencies side by side with my main jar

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to have all my dependencies side by side with my main jar in lib folder
I have added the maven-dependency-plugin configuration to the pom specifying the outputDirectory
the build is successful when running

```
mvn clean package
```

Main jar is compiled and built, but I don't see the dependencies copied, what am I doing wrong?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

maven version

```
C:\Users\user56>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (REMOVED; 2017-04-03T15:39:06-04:00)
Maven home: c:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: Could you please add logs of your Maven build?

Comment: Please add logs of `mvn clean package` not `mvn -v`

Answer (score 1):

I tried your configuration with maven 3.5 and maven-dependency-plugin 2.10, and it works. The dependencies are copied to `<project>/target/lib`. Please check your maven version (`mvn -v`) and the version of the plugin and upgrade if you're using older versions.

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Copying guava-18.0.jar to /Users/user/git/myproject/target/lib/guava-18.0.jar
```

Comment: Updated maven version in the question, and I updated my pom to use version 3.0.2 of the dependency-plugin - still nothing , what version of the maven are you using? can you include your complete pom?

Comment: Same maven version, but older dependency plugin (2.10) so versions are probably not relevant then. Please check the log to verify that the maven-dependency-plugin is actually run (like the lines I pasted above). If you can't see it, please add more context to your pom.xml in the question so I can see all xml tags above the plugin. I pasted your section into project->build->plugins.